# Working with trees as priority queues in Haskell

Tags: haskell, queue, binary-search-tree, typeclass

I have to create a binary search tree, a data type named Person, and basically insert each person in the tree. The thing is that the insertion method has a priority type, which is defined in the following peace of code:

```
class Priorities a where  

     priority :: a -> Int  


instance Priorities a where  

     priority :: a -> Int
```

Each node of the tree is a list, and the insertion is done regarding the priority number from the Priorities class, that each person was given (In my code this function is called insertTree).

Here's what I've managed to do so far:

```
data Tree => Tree a = EmptyTree  
            | Node a (Tree [a]) (Tree [a]) deriving (Show, Read, Eq)  

data Person = Person { name :: a
                 , age :: a
                 , handicapped :: a
                 } deriving (Eq)
```

Here's where I need help, because I don't know how I can do this insert. I mean, I start OK, but then I get confused when I reach the part where I need to use the priority value in to order to know in which node (which is a list), I'm going to insert the data.

```
insertTree :: (Ord a) => Priorities priority -> Tree a -> a -> Tree a  
insertTree x EmptyTree x = Node x EmptyTree EmptyTree  
insertTree x (Node a left right) y  
            |x ==  = Node y left right  
            |x
```

The other thing I'd like to ask you, is how can I make the data type People an instance of the Priorities class.

Comment: I think you need to stop for a moment and think outside of the code, how is this data structure supposed to work. For example, I don't see why you need the lists inside the tree. And if I insert let's say 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 into the tree, how should it look like?

Comment: Is it that each node should hold a list of values that are of the same priority?

Comment: @PedroRodrigues exactly!

Comment: By the way, the type `a -> int` means something entirely different from `a -> Int`.  The latter is almost certainly what you mean - watch your capitalization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your problem correctly, you tree type should be something like this:

```
data Tree a = EmptyTree
            | Node {
                nodePriority:: Int,
                nodeValues :: [a],
                leftChild :: Tree a,
                rightChild :: Tree a
              } deriving (Show, Read, Eq)
```

and then insertTree would be like:

```
...
insertTree value (Node p values left right) =
  | priority value == p = "insert value in values"
  | priority value < p = "recurse into left branch"
  | otherwise = "recurse into right branch"
```

The idea is that the nodes in the left branch have always less priority than it's parents, while the nodes in the right have always equal or bigger priority than it's parents. For example, if I insert in the following order, objects with priorities 4 2 5 1 3, yields the following tree:

```
    4
   / \
  2   5
 / \
1   3
```

Finally, to make Person an instance of Priorities you would do something like:

```
instance Priorities Person where  
     priority p = age p -- I'm using age as an example, but you can put whatever function you want
```

Comment: @dcarou That's great :)

Comment: One question: if i want more than one instance, i can just copy the "priority p" part and then write other stuff ?

Comment: @dcarou Yes, lets suppose you want make Cat an instance of Priorities, then you would just go `instance Priorities Cat where priority c = ...`. The cool thing is that insertTree would work with Cats without modifications, because it's prepared to work with any data type that is an instance of Priorities.

Comment: No, but inside the Person instance if i want more variables how would i do it ?

Comment: @dcarou I'm not sure what you mean. Do you mean creating multiple instances of Priorities for Person? Than is not possible, because then if you invoked `priority john` the compiler would have no way to know which instance of Person you wanted.

Comment: I mean if i want to create an instance of priorities for Person, and inside that instance i want to have the name, age and handicapped atributes per say

Comment: @dcarou Making Person an instance of Priorities is basically saying that "this data structure Person supports the Priorities interface, so you can ask it what is it's `priority`". You are free in the definition of `priority` to do whatever it's necessary to calculate a Person's priority. You can for example add the person's age with the length of the name: `... priority p = age p + length (name p)`.

Answer (score 0):

So basically my insertTree function it's gonna be like this:

```
insertTree value (Node p left values right)  
   | priority value == p = Node p left value right  
   | priority value < p = Node p left value (insertTree right value)  
   | otherwise = Node p (insertTree left value) value right
```

Comment: Don't forget to insert value in the list of values.

Comment: You're not updating the values list, when you found the right node to insert the value. Instead of `Node p left value right` (which doesn't type-check because `value` isn't a list) you should have `Node p left (value:values) right`.